# create table with date name

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing a simple procedure to backup a table-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE daily_backup()
BEGIN
   DECLARE given_date VARCHAR(25);
   SET given_date = now(); 

   CREATE TABLE given_date LIKE db1.table1;
   INSERT INTO given_date SELECT * FROM db1.table1;


END
```

But it creates a table with name given_date . I want to create a table with date as name. 
How to do the same ?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17106254/330315

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This one

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS daily_backup;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE daily_backup()
BEGIN
    DECLARE given_datetime VARCHAR(25);
    DECLARE backup_table VARCHAR(64);

    SET given_datetime = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d_%H%i%s');

    /**We need to add backticks to forcibly create table name as current date and time **/
    SET backup_table = CONCAT('db.table1_',given_datetime);
    SET @modified_date = CONCAT('`',backup_table,'`');
    SET @create_sql := CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', @modified_date, ' LIKE db1.table1;');
    prepare stmt from @create_sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


    SET @insert_sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', @modified_date, ' SELECT * FROM db1.table1;');
    prepare stmt1 from @insert_sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;


END //
DELIMITER ;
CALL daily_backup();
```

**UPDATE**

> We cant create table directly as CREATE TABLE 2013-06-14 16:58:37 LIKE db1.table;
>
> But we can create it forcibly by adding backtics in table name as
>
> CREATE TABLE `2013-06-14 16:58:37` LIKE db1.table;

**UPDATE by RolandoMySQLDBA**

> I changed the code to have datetime appended to the backup.
>
> The backup will be named db1.table1_YYYMMDD_HHMMSS
>
> The algorithm itself is fine (+1) !!!

Answer (score 2):

not fully sure this is the syntax for mysql, but it should be close:

```
PREPARE statemt FROM CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', given_date, ' LIKE db1.table1;');
EXECUTE statemt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statemt;
```

then you can do the same for the insert

Edit by RolandoMySQLDBA

You were close (+1). This is a little closer:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', given_date, ' LIKE db1.table1;');
PREPARE statemt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE statemt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statemt;
```